# What (kind of?) brake lever is this?

Tags: road-bike, brakes, fixed-gear, brake-levers

I'm curious as to whether or not anyone knows who makes this brake lever or if anyone makes one like it. I know the bike in the image is a Montreal-based company called Bassi that primarily sells through the shop in the same town called "C&L Cycles" however I emailed them and received no response. I appreciate any and all help! Thank you!

[image: brake lever]

Here is another image of the brake lever on the bike

[image: brake lever with bike]

Comment: Could that bike get anymore hipster?

Comment: Surely it should be on the left hand side of the stem.

Comment: I'd love to see a video of someone using this, I imagine trying to stop suddenly with hands this close together would end in a catastrophic case of the wobbles. Which would damage your wooden bar!

Comment: In late 2017 those image links are dead. This is why image links should be avoided, and images be uploaded to stackexchange directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's almost certainly a Gran Compe SHOT LEVER two handle brake lever. [This description](http://www.bikeradar.com/au/gear/category/components/brake-levers/product/review-dia-compe-gran-compe-shot-brake-lever-09-34446/) matches quite well and there's [some comments on Bike Forums](http://www.bikeforums.net/singlespeed-fixed-gear/723571-gran-compe-shot-lever-two-handle-brake-lever.html).

[image]

Simply, both levers operate the same brake, but on a narrow bar where you don't have room for two levers for two brakes it's a good compromise.

Answer (score 3):

It is a Gran Compe Shot Lever from Dia Compe.  I have one on my Stelbel fixie, and one on my Colnago single speed.  They work fantastically; however, the photo at the bottom (white handlebar tape) has the lever mounted backwards.  Make sure the long arm goes across the stem.